# Use MemoryStream (or other) as circular buffer for TCP communication

Tags: c#, stream, circular-buffer

I am in the process of simplifying/optimizing some code I wrote a while ago. I had created a custom circular buffer class that served it's purpose but I am hoping to replace it with something more standard for any consuming code.

The requirements are (and what my `CircularBuffer` aleady does):

1. Ability to peek (read without permanently consuming) *more* than one byte. This is required because the network messages have a two byte length prefix and i'd rather not buffer a buffer.
2. Starts writing from the beginning once it reaches it's maximum length (circular)
3. Ability to throw an exception when it overflows (overwrites non-consumed data)

What would also be nice is the ability to write and read at the same time, something I never got around to figuring out in my circular buffer.

I have my eye on `MemoryStream` but from the documentation I can't determine if it satisfies #2 and #3.

So, are there any streams that support/can support (with modification) my requirements, or am I stuck creating my own custom circular buffer?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. What did you decide?

Comment: @John I began using `Pipelines` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/07/09/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/. Basically it's streams on steroids. Internally, all the buffering is pre-allocated and re-used. It's not *truly* a circular buffer but all of that stuff is abstracted away so you don't even need to concern yourself with it anymore. You'll probably be most interested in the "back pressure" feature of pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the memory buffer out of the box supports `#2` and `#3`. 
Maybe the `Queue` could be the base for a ring buffer.

It is a FIFO structure, new content is always added at the and it reads from the beginning. To make this a ring-buffer with a certain size, you could throw an exception if `Queue.Count()` exceeds a specified value.

This could have the advantage, that you don't need a maximum size at all, the Queue will grow and shrink with the available data.

Random access is possible via LINQ, `var nThElement = Queue.ElementAt(...);`, although this could be performance heavy if done extensively.

But for something as specific as this, I personally would go with the custom implementation you already have.